# Filter out rows with date range gaps in mysql

Tags: mysql, date-range, self-join, gaps-and-islands

In mysql I have a table similar to the following one:

```
--------------------------------------------
| id | parent_id | date_start | date_end   |
--------------------------------------------
| 1  |           | 2017-05-01 | 2017-05-10 |
| 2  | 1         | 2017-05-01 | 2017-05-10 |
| 3  |           | 2017-06-01 | 2017-06-10 |
| 4  | 3         | 2017-06-01 | 2017-06-03 |
| 5  | 3         | 2017-06-04 | 2017-06-06 |
| 6  | 3         | 2017-06-07 | 2017-06-10 |
| 7  |           | 2017-07-01 | 2017-07-10 |
| 8  | 7         | 2017-07-01 | 2017-07-03 |
| 9  | 7         | 2017-07-04 | 2017-07-06 |
| 10 | 7         | 2017-07-08 | 2017-07-10 |
```

rows without parent id are "pricelists" while rows with parent are pricelist periods.
I'd want to filter out pricelist ids with periods that have time gaps, so ideally my query should return 1 and 3.
So far I've written a simple query which correctly returns 3:

```
SELECT distinct period1.parent_id
FROM pricelist period1
INNER JOIN pricelist period2
ON period1.parent_id = period2.parent_id
AND period2.date_start = DATE_ADD(period1.date_end,INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

but unfortunately it doesn't take into account pricelists with a single period, which have no gaps by definition!

So I was wondering if it could be possible to modify such a query to return pricelists with either single periods or multiple periods without time gaps, possibly without a UNION.

Comment: Is the query you included the one that gets the "3".  I made a fiddle <http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de7e3/2> and get 3 and 7.  Still wrong, but it makes me wonder what's missing.

Comment: don't know... maybe it has to do with foreign key between id and parent_id

Answer (score 0):

I had difficulty finding a MySQL workspace so initially I presented a T-SQL solution, but have subsequently learned how to use MySQL at rextester which has helped a lot. The syntax for the DATEDIFF() function in MySQL is the opposite logic to T-SQL which became complex without an ability to test it. Hopefully now resolved.

The basic logic of this approach is to calculate the overall duration of the parents. Then to calculate the sum of duration of all the children. Then compare these durations (in a join) and if they are the same you have no gaps.

Note this logic isn't tested for overlaps in children but I would expect thses to also fail at the join where durations are compared.

**Data:**

```
#drop table if exists `PRICELIST`;

create table `PRICELIST`
    (`id` int, `parent_id` int, `date_start` datetime, `date_end` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO PRICELIST
    (`id`, `parent_id`, `date_start`, `date_end`)
VALUES
    (1, NULL, '2017-05-01 00:00:00', '2017-05-10 00:00:00'),
    (2, 1, '2017-05-01 00:00:00', '2017-05-10 00:00:00'),
    (3, NULL, '2017-06-01 00:00:00', '2017-06-10 00:00:00'),
    (4, 3, '2017-06-01 00:00:00', '2017-06-03 00:00:00'),
    (5, 3, '2017-06-04 00:00:00', '2017-06-06 00:00:00'),
    (6, 3, '2017-06-07 00:00:00', '2017-06-10 00:00:00'),
    (7, NULL, '2017-07-01 00:00:00', '2017-07-10 00:00:00'),
    (8, 7, '2017-07-01 00:00:00', '2017-07-03 00:00:00'),
    (9, 7, '2017-07-04 00:00:00', '2017-07-06 00:00:00'),
    (10, 7, '2017-07-08 00:00:00', '2017-07-10 00:00:00')
;
```

**MySQL:**

```
select p.id, datediff(p.date_end,p.date_start) pdu, x.du
from pricelist p
inner join (
        select
        p1.parent_id, sum(datediff(p1.date_end,p1.date_start) + coalesce(datediff(p2.date_start,p1.date_end),0)) du
        from (
            select parent_id,date_start,date_end
            from pricelist
            where parent_id IS NOT NULL
             ) p1
        left join (
            select parent_id,date_start,date_end
            from pricelist
            where parent_id IS NOT NULL
             ) p2 on p1.parent_id = p2.parent_id and p1.date_end < p2.date_start
        where datediff(p2.date_start,p1.date_end) = 1 or p2.parent_id is null
        group by p1.parent_id
    ) x on p.id = x.parent_id and datediff(p.date_end,p.date_start) = x.du
where p.parent_id IS NULL
;
```

see it working at: http://rextester.com/JRD47056

**T-SQL:**

Whilst I could not find a MySQL environment that worked, I used MSSQL but avoided any analytic functions etc that can't be used in MySQL. However I have relied on datediff() which is slightly different to the same function in MySQL.

TSQL query

```
select p.id, datediff(day,p.date_start,p.date_end) du
from @pricelist p
inner join (
        select
        p1.parent_id, sum(datediff(day,p1.date_start,p1.date_end) + coalesce(datediff(day,p1.date_end,p2.date_start),0)) du
        from (
            select parent_id,date_start,date_end
            from @pricelist
            where parent_id IS NOT NULL
             ) p1
        left join (
            select parent_id,date_start,date_end
            from @pricelist
            where parent_id IS NOT NULL
             ) p2 on p1.parent_id = p2.parent_id and p1.date_end < p2.date_start
        where datediff(day,p1.date_end,p2.date_start) = 1 or p2.parent_id is null
        group by p1.parent_id
    ) x on p.id = x.parent_id and datediff(day,p.date_start,p.date_end) = x.du
where p.parent_id IS NULL
```

see it working at: http://rextester.com/KUK2410

---

In MySQL the datediff() expects just 2 parameters and ou need to swap the field references (i.e. latest date first)

Perhaps there are easier ways. Best I could come up with for now.

Comment: in mysql it does return 1 whereas it should return 1 and 3

Comment: Have you reversed the parameters in the datediff function? i.e datediff(end,start) : but in mSsql it is datediff(unit,start,end)

Comment: I have added a mysql solution.